# How to mock the method calls with wildcard parameter in Rspec?

Tags: ruby, rspec, wildcard

This is my production code

```
def my_method
    list = [.....]
    list.each do |filename|
        content = File.read(filename)
        ...
    end
end
```

I am writing an unit test in Rspec, so how to mock the File.read using wildcard parameter?

```
File.should_receive(:read).with(??some regex here).and_return ""
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`anything`](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/2-11/docs/argument-matchers/general-matchers#anything-argument-matcher) or `any_args`.

```
File.should_receive(:read).with(anything).and_return ""
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regular expression matcher like this, to match "barn":

```
File.should_receive(:read).with(/bar/).and_return ""
```

More details can be found in the [RSpec Mocks 3.2 Matching arguments documentation](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/v/3-2/docs/setting-constraints/matching-arguments)